# Remove version control from Eclipose RCP project

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, egit, jgit

I have an Eclipse RCP application that uses EGit and JGit to implement the version control of projects.

In some cases, I want to make it so that a project is no longer under version control. This implies both deleting the project's .git directory on the file system, and making my application aware that the project is not under version control.

I tried looking through the JGit API for solutions to this, but could not find anything useful. Simply deleting the .git directory using a file manipulation API is not sufficient, as some files in it seem to be locked (very likely by JGit).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I'm not 100% sure because your scenario is not clear enough to me, however you said that your application is based also on EGit, so I assume that you are using the standard eclipse APIs to manage the projects. If this is the case, what you are looking for is: `org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider`

This is an example:

```
public class UntrackProject extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IProject project = getProject(); // get the project, for example using the selection service

        try {
            RepositoryProvider.unmap(project);

            //TODO Refresh your viewer to show changes

        } catch (TeamException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

For reference, you can check the handler of the context menu "Disconnect", that does exactly what you are looking for: `org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.actions.DisconnectActionHandler`
https://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/tree/org.eclipse.egit.ui/src/org/eclipse/egit/ui/internal/actions/DisconnectActionHandler.java

It uses a lot of internal classes of egit, but in the end it uses the RepositoryProvider's API.

Note that the method `RepositoryProvider.unmap(project)` does NOT delete the repository, it just disconnects the project.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the hint - I was not aware of the unmap(project) method. However, it looks like calling this method does not release the file system lock on the .git directory. So it is still not possible to delete this directory programmatically from within my application.

Comment: I should add that if the .git directory is not deleted, EGit still sees the project as being under version control after restarting the application.

Comment: That sounds a little weird. I wonder what is locking the .git directory!